# Azure Table Storage, ExecuteBatchAsync, Unexpected response code for operation : 0

Tags: c#, json, azure-table-storage

By leveraging the Windows Azure SDK, I try to insert entities using CloudTable.ExecuteBatchAsync and TableBatchOperations.

The entity serialized as Json:

```
{
    "LastAccessDate":"2015-02-27T00:00:00Z",
    "Title":"Google open-sources HTTP/2-based RPC framework",
    "PublicationDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Id":"tag:theregister.co.uk,2005:story/2015/02/27/google_opensources_http2based_rpc_framework/",
    "LastUpdatedDate":"2015-02-27T00:00:00Z",
    "FeedUrl":"http://www.theregister.co.uk/software/developer/headlines.atom",
    "Url":"http://go.theregister.com/feed/www.theregister.co.uk/2015/02/27/google_opensources_http2based_rpc_framework/",
    "PartitionKey":"http%3a%2f%2fwww.theregister.co.uk%2fsoftware%2fdeveloper%2fheadlines.atom",
    "RowKey":"http%3a%2f%2fgo.theregister.com%2ffeed%2fwww.theregister.co.uk%2f2015%2f02%2f27%2fgoogle_opensources_http2based_rpc_framework%2f",
    "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
    "ETag":null
}
```

Represented by this POCO entity:

```
public class SyndicationFeedArticle : TableEntity
{        
    public virtual DateTime LastAccessDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string FeedUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
}
```

The problem arises when the entity is constructed from RSS xml processing. ExecuteBatch of inserts throws `Unexpected response code for operation : 0`. I do understand that it means that the batch operation at index 0 failed. Usually it's a problem with either Partition or Row keys being incorrect such as containing invalid characters (which is not the case above) or exceeding 1kb in size which in this case doesn't apply.

Here's what puzzling me:

- Both unit test and business code entities (although constructed differently) generate the exact same Json serialization data
- Both processes (manual `new()` creation and RSS business code) works well in a Unit test
- There is no issue at all when storing on the Emulator, it fails in Azure Cloud only.

What I'm looking for are pointers on how I could troubleshoot this issue. I've recreated various scenarios in unit tests and made sure my entities don't break constraints on keys but no luck. My main issue is why can't I get constant behaviours between the emulator and the cloud. This would really help me out or at least, it would point me toward another way to fix this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it figured out. 
What happens in this particular scenario:

`PublicationDate` is instantiated using a DateTimeOffset.Date as source value which may be set at MinValue. The table storage doesn't support MinValue for a DateTime column.

`<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>OutOfRangeInput</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">One of the request inputs is out of range. RequestId:9e74bf7a-0002-004e-1142-16dabb000000 Time:2015-02-28T02:01:42.2124803Z</message>
</error>`

I changed the entity property for a `DateTime?` and manages this as a business rule. Of course, I'm left wondering why locally on the emulator this is supported...